# how to remove gray background of the popup .net maui?

Tags: .net, xaml, xamarin, popup, maui

I am trying to build a popup to show it when there is an error , in the code below it show a popup with a big gray background as it show it image I tried to fix height and width but didn't work , but if I remove the border the popup display without the gray background (I don't know why) the same thing for frame .

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<toolkit:Popup xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"  
             x:Class="MauiApp14.Popuppage"
              >
    
    <Border BackgroundColor="Green" MaximumWidthRequest="200" MaximumHeightRequest="200"  Stroke="#E9E7E6"  StrokeShape = "RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" x:Name="target">
        <Label 
            HeightRequest="200"
            WidthRequest="200"
            Background="red"
            FontSize="30"
            TextColor="White" 
            HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
            VerticalTextAlignment="Center"
            Text="Error 404 not found "
           
            />
    </Border>
   
</toolkit:Popup>
```

[image]

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve thanks the problem was that I should put the heightRequest and widthRequest in the border element and not in the label

Comment: Yes. I've explained in detail in my answer. Please accept it if it helped you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MaximumWidthRequest` (and similar for Height) doesn't do what you think.
Your version causes popup to use its default dimensions, because it does not know what Width/Height are wanted, because its child (`Border`) does not specify `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`.

Fix:

- Remove `Maximum` from those, so `WidthRequest` and `HeightRequest`:
  `<Border ... WidthRequest="200" ...>`

NOTE: It worked without `Border`, because then popup's child (`Label`) *does* specify Width/Height.

Comment: I tried it but I think popup elements don't have widthRequests and other attributes

Comment: Are you saying that the second suggestion, `Popuppage WidthRequest=...` doesn't have those attributes? I'll remove that from the answer. **The first suggestion works, right?** Its the same as your comment.